# javaFX and XML data storing

Tags: java, xml, javafx, javafx-2

I am currently developing a javafx application. basically it's a simple database application that enables users to add, view, delete and edit stuffs. Now I am having a problem to store data in XML database form.

Now. I have a main class which consists of a function that displays a rootLayout (menuBar)
and a tab pane. My tab pane consists of 3 tab. (BOOK, CD and STATIONERY).

I got Main class, 
TabPaneController class which consists of BOOK, CD and STATIONERY layout,
A controller for each of the categories (BOOK, CD and STATIONERY).

And so far. I don't know where to put the save and load methods.

I am using XStream.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am following this question correctly it sounds like you are unsure as to where to actually call the save and load functions?

FX is *very* different to swing, it does a lot of behind the scenes work for users in terms of dependency injections. You have probably already noticed that there is no call to the constructor of your controller (barring the obvious parameterless constructor).

From a design perspective, you should initiate this call in the constructor. The save could be attached to a button and perform this function in a background thread (for example).

Load should be done when your constructor is initialised.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
  SomeDataType data = someController.loadData();
  yourView.setData(data);
}
```

Now, depending on the component it will have some type of observable model that you should conform to. You should also keep in mind that if you don't handle exceptions here your controller will not correctly initialise.

If this doesn't help can you post some code for clarity sakes? Possibly even a stack trace if you are encountering one?